# Refactoring Crossrider extension code

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, include, browser-extension, crossrider

I  built my extension using [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/developers) and at the moment all my code is in the *extension.js* file. However, it's getting rather long and becoming more difficult to maintain in this monolithic file. Is there a way to split my code into separate files and still use them in my extension?

So for example, if I my *extension.js* file is structured like the following example, I would like functions f1 & f2 to be in a separate file that I can load into the extension:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  init();
  f1();
  f2();
  ...

  function init() {
    // init code
    ...
  }
  function f1() {
    //hundreds of lines of code
  }
  function f2() {
    //hundreds of lines of code
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define the functions in one or more resource files (e.g. *init.js*, *functions.js*) and then include it from within [appAPI.ready](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-ready). For more information about resources, see [appAPI.resources](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources).

So, using your example, your code would be something like:

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.resources.includeJS('init.js');
  appAPI.resources.includeJS('functions.js');
  init();
  f1();
  f2();
  ...
});
```

**init.js**:

```
function init() {
  // init code
  ...
}
```

**functions.js**:

```
function f1() {
  //hundreds of lines of code
}
function f2() {
  //hundreds of lines of code
}
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]